# Reference request for localization needed for project in algebraic geometry.

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation, algebraic-curves, localization

I am doing a reading project on *algebraic curves* and I need to learn about the concept of *localization* from commutative algebra for understanding the project topic.But my commutative algebra background is not so strong and so I do not know which book will be suitable for me.I know one commutative algebra book by *Atyiah-MacDonald*  but I think it is not good for a reader who has no background in commutative algebra.So,can someone suggest me some reference from which I can get sufficient knowledge about localization so as to do my project work.

Comment: If you're working on algebraic curves then you will need to learn commutative algebra, so you might as well acquire the background.

Comment: My favourite book for Commutative Algebra is the one by Altman and Kleiman. It includes localisation.

Comment: Sharing some links wait.

Comment: https://youtube.com/@user-gq1mx4jb5l

Comment: This link is from one my favorite teacher from Bmath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "So,can someone suggest me some reference from which I can get sufficient knowledge about localization so as to do my project work."

**Answer:** Matsumura, "Commutative ring theory" has a section with an introduction to localization. The book uses localization systematically to study commutative rings and modules, flatness etc.